# Executing SQL Statements on same postgresql database but multiple servers at the same time with PGAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

We developed software that is installed on tens of servers (each client requires his own server). Whenever an update is required to a table or an alter table is needed for example, I have to go to each server in PGAdmin and execute the statement(s) on them. Is there any way I can connect to all servers for example in PGAdmin, and execute the statements on all of them at once?

Note that it is the same product so all databases and table names are identical but on many servers, so it will be helpful to execute one alter statement for example on all of them rather than doing this one by one.

I prefer to have a solution using the PGAdmin (with UI not code).

Thanks.

Comment: We have been using Dbeaver to execute a command in many servers, although it works the interface doesn't fit our requirements, so finally we made our own tool. I can't understand why there is no easy way to execute a sentence or script in many servers.

Comment: @rasputino Thanks, I will check this DBeaver and give it a look, something better than nothing :)

Comment: @rasputino I managed to achieve everything required with this DBeaver! it is a pretty much nice tool. Thanks for that. If you didn't check it recently then I recommend you do because they made many updates to it... please put your comment in a post to mark it as a correct answer :) thanks

Comment: What's wrong with code? It sounds like already write SQL statements as code anyway.

Comment: @Bergi why should I write code, and deploy on all servers, to execute a small update query for example? DBeaver was the solution for me. You put the query you want and execute it to the servers you want without the need of any code intervention. Thanks

Comment: Who said anything about deploying code to all servers? You're already writing SQL code to execute, you could trivially use a script (e.g. with `psql`) that connects to all your databases to execute it multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been using DBeaver to execute a command in many servers, although it works the interface doesn't fit our requirements, so finally we made our own tool. I can't understand why there is no easy way to execute a sentence or script in many servers.